# Running Keycloak container behing Nginx Reverse proxy with Docker swarm

Tags: docker, nginx, keycloak, redhat, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to run the Keycloak container in a non-root path ( /auth ) behind a nginx reverse proxy in docker swarm mode.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest as builder

# Enable health and metrics support
ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true


# Configure a database vendor
ENV KC_DB=mysql

WORKDIR /opt/keycloak

#Generating a Self-Signed Certificate
RUN keytool -genkeypair -storepass password -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=server" -alias server -ext "SAN:c=DNS:app.example.com" -keystore conf/server.keystore
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/

#change these values to point to a running Mysql instance
ENV KC_DB=mysql
ENV KC_DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://keycloak_database:3306/keycloak
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=keycloak
ENV KC_HOSTNAME_URL=https://app.example.com/auth/
ENV KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL=https://app.example.com/auth/
ENV KC_PROXY=edge
ENV KC_LOG_LEVEL=INFO
ENV KC_HOSTNAME_DEBUG=true
ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]
```

Using the above docker file I have used this command to run the keycloak service in which keycloakpro is the image name

```
docker service create --name keycloak --network test_overlay --constraint node.labels.server==true --env KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin --env KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin keycloakpro start --optimized
```

This is my nginx reverse proxy configuration,

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name app.example.com;
        ssl_certificate /home/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/private.key;
        
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;


     

        location /backend {
                    rewrite ^/backend(.*)$ $1 break;
                    proxy_pass http://backend-server:9999/;
                    proxy_redirect off;
        }
        
        
        location /auth {
                    rewrite ^/auth(.*)$ $1 break;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host app.example.com;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 8443;
                    proxy_pass https://keycloak:8443/;
                    add_header Set-Cookie $http_cookie;
       
        }
    
        location / {
                    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1 break;
                    proxy_pass http://react-server/;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection ‘upgrade’;
                    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        }
        
    
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name app.example.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

In the above nginx configuration, I have a backend service running in the "/backend" location block and a react server served by nginx in the root path.

When all the above configurations are used together, keycloak will be accessible through https://app.example.com/auth

When I go to https://app.example.com/auth/, it redirects me to the Keycloak page. This URL takes me to the admin's page: https://app.example.com/auth/admin/.

This will initiate the OAuth2 flow login page: https://app.example.com/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=security-admin-console ...

Once I reach this point, Keycloak will store a cookie in the browser, which is not happening in my case. If I access it using https://app.example.com:8443/, the cookie is set, and I am unable to log in. Only if the request goes throw proxy it won't set the cookie.

I have checked various articles related to this but none of them are able to solve my issue.
Any help is appreciated.

[image: Keycloak home page]

[image: Keycloak login page]

[image: Keycloak error page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my mistake actually, I was ignoring the cookie headers in the nginx.conf file of the reverse proxy due to which I got the above issue.
To be more specific it's because of these lines,

```
proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control Set-Cookie;
proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
```

Commenting these two lines out did the trick.